# How to send a multiline request which starts and ends with Unicodes ( including Unicodes ) from the JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to send a request (multiline message not a single line from a text file)  starts with Unicode (\u0001)(^A) and ends with another Unicode (\u0003)(^C)  including these Unicodes from JMeter?

example of the requests contains in a text file :
eg1:

```
^A1stline^M
2ndline^M
^B3rdline^M
4thline^M
5th line^M
5th line^M
6th line^M
7th line^M
8th line^M
^C
```

eg2:

```
^Afirstline^M
 secondline^M
^Bthirdline^M
fourthline^M
fifthline^M
^C
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) somewhere to the beginning of your Thread Group
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def values = (new File('/path/to/your/file.txt').text =~ /(?s)(\u0001.*?\u0003)/)

   values.eachWithIndex { value, index ->
       vars.put('value_' + (index + 1), value[1])
   }
   ```
3. It will create the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

   - `${value_1}` - with the contents of your `eg1`
   - `${value_2}` - with the contents of your `eg2`
   - etc.

   these variables can be iterated using [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter